# Как правильно пользоваться паттерном PageObject

Tags: java, шаблоны-проектирования, selenium-webdriver, ui, test-automation

Пытаюсь разобраться с паттерном `Page object` и возник вопрос:
Пытаюсь автоматизировать тестирование сайта на котором есть

1)Страница входа(логин/пароль/кнопка входа).
2)После ввода логина и пароля нас переводит на страницу c "*ВашАккаунт*".
На странице *ВашАккаунт* есть кнопка "*Создать обьяление*"
После нажатия на кнопку происходит переход страницу с полями которые необходимо заполнить.

Для автоматизации тестирования страницы при использовании паттерна `Page object` нужно:

Создать класс для логина:

```
public class AutoQALogin {

WebDriver driver;
By userName = By.id("user_login");
By password = By.id("user_pass");
By login = By.id("wp-submit");

public AutoQALogin(WebDriver driver){
    this.driver = driver;
}

//Set user name in textbox
public void setUserName(String strUserName){
    driver.findElement(userName).sendKeys(strUserName);
}

//Set password in password textbox
public void setPassword(String strPassword){
     driver.findElement(password).sendKeys(strPassword);
}

//Click on login button
public void clickLogin(){
        driver.findElement(login).click();
}

public void loginToAutoQA(String strUserName,String strPasword){
    //Fill user name
    this.setUserName(strUserName);
    //Fill password
    this.setPassword(strPasword);
    //Click Login button
    this.clickLogin();      
    }
}
```

Создать класс для создания обьявления:

```
    public class AutoQAcreateMail{  
WebDriver driver;
By captionName = By.xpath("//*[@id="title"]/div[1]/label");
By description= By.xpath("//*[@id="description"]/div[1]/label");
By createButton= By.xpath("//*[@id="button"]");

public AutoQAcreateMail(WebDriver driver){
    this.driver = driver;
}

//Set tools name in captionName 
public void setCaptionName(String captionName){
    driver.findElement(captionName).sendKeys(captionName);
}

//Set description in description textbox
public void setDescription(String description){
     driver.findElement(description).sendKeys(description);
}

//Click on create button
public void clickCreate(){
    driver.findElement(createButton).click();
}

public void createMail(String strCaptionName, String strDescription){
    //Fill Caption Name
    this.setCaptionName(strCaptionName);
    //Fill Description
    this.setDescription(strDescription);
    //Click Create button
    this.clickCreate();       
    }  
}
```

Выполнение теста

```
public class TestAutoQALogin {

WebDriver driver;
AutoQALogin objLogin;
AutoQAHomePage objHomePage;

@BeforeTest
public void setup(){
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("http://autoqa.pp.ua/wp-login.php");
}

@Test(priority=0)
public void test_Home_Page_Appear_Correct(){

objLogin = new AutoQALogin(driver);
//login to application
objLogin.loginToAutoQA("subscriber", "subscriberpass");
// go the next page
objMailPage = new AutoQAcreateMail(driver);
//Create mail
createMail("testFillCaption", "testFillDecRiption")

//Verify create mail
Assert.assertTrue(objMailPage.getHomePageDashboardName().toLowerCase().contains("profile"));
    }
}
```

Так вот подскажите правильно ли я все делаю согласно паттерну `Page Object`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это не лучший способ реализации данного шаблона, потому что в вашем классе `AutoQAcreateMail` по сути действия выполняются над страницей `AutoQALogin`, а это не есть хорошо.

Предлагаю ознакомиться с [данным туториалом](https://kreisfahrer.gitbooks.io/selenium-webdriver/content/page_object_pattern_arhitektura_testovogo_proekta/ispolzovanie_patterna_page_object.html) по реализации паттерна PageObject. 
Здесь основная идея заключается в том, что методы конкретной страницы возвращают новое состояние текущей страницы:

```
public LoginPage typeUsername(String username) {
    driver.findElement(usernameLocator).sendKeys(username);
    return this;    
})
```

либо возвращают страницу, на которую осуществляется переход после выполнения определенного действия:

```
public HomePage submitLogin() {
    driver.findElement(loginButtonLocator).submit();
    return new HomePage(driver);    
}
```

В вашем случае необходимо будет создать **3 класса**: "Страница входа", "Страница Ваш аккаунт", "Страница с формой заполнения".

И никаких переходных классов наподобие `AutoQAcreateMail` не нужно создавать. Если в приложении есть всего 3 страницы HTML, то всего будет 3 класса, описывающих страницы. Больше классов не следует создавать.

**UPD.** Единственный минус данной реализации - это то, что при большом количестве переходов между страницами каждый раз будет создаваться новый объект, т.е. необходимо задуматься о том, как хранить состояния страниц. Для этого можно использовать один из нижеперечисленных способов:

- передавать в метод старый экземпляр страницы;
- создать конструктор, инициализирующий состояние страницы.